# What is the best way to display a tree-like node structure in a tableView with the API response data sorted in Swift?

Tags: swift, api, sorting, tableview, nodes

I am new to iOS development and I need to sort an array in tree order and display it in tableView. I am given a node struct with id and parentId, if parentId is zero then it is main category, else it is subcategory.

```
struct Category {
var id: Int?
var parentId: Int?
var childs: \[Category\]?
}
```

Lets assume that API response is like this:

```
"category_list": {
"count": 10_000,
"array": [
{
"id": 14,
"parent_id": 0,
"childs": [Category]
},
{
"id": 127,
"parent_id": 14,
"childs": [Category]
},
{
"id": 92,
"parent_id": 26,
"childs": [Category]
},
...
]
}
```

Here is my code for sorting, but it is not working:

```
class CategoryViewModel {
var categories = [Category]()

func makeTree(list: [Category]) -> [Category] {
    categories = list
    var groupedCategories: [Category] = []

    for i in list {
        if i.parentId == 0 {
            //main category
            groupedCategories.append(Category(id: i.id,
                                              parentId: i.parentId,
                                              childs: getChildren(parentId: i.parentId)))
        }
    }
    return groupedCategories
}

private func getChildren(parentId: Int?) -> [Category] {
    var childs = [Category]()
    
    for i in categories {
        if parentId == i.parentId {
            childs.append(Category(id: i.id,
                                   parentId: i.parentId,
                                   childs: getChildren(parentId: i.parentId)))
        }
    }
    return childs
}
}
```

[The output should look like this in tableView, also I don't have any idea how to show elements of array in the order like in picture and how many rows to return:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSrgd.png)

Comment: Why is id and parentId optional for Category?

Comment: Are you responsible for the backend? If yes send the data in the expected node structure. And I agree with Joakim: There is no reason to declare both `id` struct members optional. And what are the backslashes for?

Comment: @vadian Hi, I applied for internship and HR manager sent me this task. I am mobile developer(ios). Just ignore those backslashes in struct.